# Group by and where?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to calculate some columns in a mysql database with this code:

```
"SELECT SUM(klick) FROM svar GROUP BY pollid HAVING pollID="& rstPoll("PollId")
```

But it doesn't work. So what I want to do is to get the sum of all "klick" where a pollId has a certain value. I got this code to work with access but not with mysql:

```
"SELECT SUM(klick) FROM svar WHERE pollID="& rstPoll("PollId"))
```

Some lines in the database:
id: 180
klick: 10
pollid: 56

id: 181
klick: 53
pollid: 56

id: 182
klick: 10
pollid: 56

Now I want the sum of all the klick where pollId = 56 for example. So the results here would be: 73

Comment: It's just a integer. I get not error message by the way, I just do not get any result back.

Comment: It's just an integer. I get not error message btw, just no result back.*

Comment: What's the host language? VB? Is the value of '`rstPoll("PollId")`' a single integer? Is the value a valid pollID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what this rstPoll() business is but this is entirely valid MySQL SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(klick) FROM svar WHERE pollID = 1234
```

assuming pollID is a numeric type. And it will do what you expect so you've got something else going on.

Comment: This works now. Wow. I don't know why it didn't work before.

I'm sorry for asking this stupid question but thank you everyone for the answers, they helped me very much.

Answer (score 2):

to just get the sum of klick for a particular pollID you don’t need a group by clause:

```
SELECT SUM(klick)
  FROM svar
 WHERE pollID = %d
```

Comment: i think i got your question wrong. what exactly do you want as a result? can you show an example table with few lines and the expected result?

Comment: some lines in the database
id: 180
klick: 10
pollid: 56

id: 181
klick: 53
pollid: 56

id: 182
klick: 10
pollid: 56

Now I want the sum of all the klick where pollId = 56 for example. So the results here would be: 73

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm sorry I can't vote for your answer but I haven't registered me yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your second query is correct. You must have a problem comparing two different types: pollID and whatever rstPoll("PollId") returns.